# Rails: Landing Page without controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

New to rails and I need to make a homepage for my website. I have 3 controllers that will be linked to from the homepage. I don't want to create another controller for the homepage. For example:

I want homepage to be: 
    http://samplepage.com

The homepage will link to:
    http://samplepage.com/apples
    http://samplepage.com/bananas
    http://samplepage.com/carrots

How do I set up the root route?
I already have functioning pages for /apples, /banana, /carrots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you can use any of your controllers to setup the home page eg:

```
ApplesController
  def home
    # intialize instance variable for home page here
  end
  . . . . .
end
```

Create view file in app/views/apples/home.html.erb

In your routes

```
route "apples#home"
```

Comment: This worked when I put this:
    ApplesController
        def home
            render :home
        end

Is there a better way to do it? What do you mean by "initialize instance variable for home page here"?

Comment: Do you have any models?

Comment: Yes. I have models for apples, bananas, and carrots, but all that's in those models are validations.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [high_voltage](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage). You will still need to create single controller for your static pages but other than that looks like it what you look for.